# undo str_split to combine words is a paragraph? (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

I currently have a list of 27 paragraphs called `psw_list` and can refer to the first one by calling `psw_list$p1`, and it looks like this:

```
> psw_list$p1

 [1] "For"          "more"         "than"         "five"         "years,"       "William"      "Sencion"     
 [8] "did"          "the"          "same"         "task"         "over"         "and"          "over."       
[15] "He"           "signed"       "onto"         "the"          "New"          "York"         "City’s"      
[22] "housing"      "lottery"      "site"         "and"          "applied"      "for"          "one"         
[29] "of"           "the"          "city’s"       "highly"       "coveted,"     "below-market" "apartments." 
[36] "Each"         "time,"        "he"           "got"          "the"          "same"         "response:"   
[43] "silence."
```

I want to remove the spaces between each word and this  line does so to individual lines, `paste(psw_list$p1,collapse=" ")`, but does not work in a for loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(psw_list)) {
  print(paste(psw_list$[i], collapse = " "))
}
```

I'm getting an `unexpected '['` error when  I run this loop. I want the for loop because I want it to go through each paragraph and collapse the words together separated by that one space, any ideas?

Comment: Try using `sw_list[[i]]` if you want to loop over each element of the list.

Comment: Do you mean in the parameters for the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without the `for`-loop:

```
lapply(psw_list, paste, collapse = " ")
```

or if you really want the `for`-loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(psw_list)) {
  print(paste(psw_list[[i]], collapse = " "))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to `psw_list$[i]` if you replace this with `psw_list[[i]]` which selects the column `i` it will run without a problem.

Another solution to this would be to use the `apply()` family. For instance running the following:

```
lapply(psw_list, function(i) paste(i, collapse = " "))
```